# How to subset a unigue value in a column from data.table to new data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that I am wanting to subset and create another data.table based on the Counter variable.

The pseudo code would be
create a new data.table of only unique `Subject` from old data.table where `Counter` is = 5

`new_data <- old_data[Counter == 5, ]`

but will this give me every time the counter reaches 5, I need it to only give it to me the first time

```
Old data.table:
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| Date          | Subject    | Counter      | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-21-20      |   a        |   0          |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-22-20      |   a        |   1          |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-23-20      |   a        |   2          |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-21-20      |   b        |   0          |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-26-20      |   b        |   5          |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 11-2-20       |   b        |   5          | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+  
| 11-7-20       |   b        |   5          | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

```
New data.table
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-26-20      |   b        |   5          |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can wrap with `unique` to get the first row `by` the 'Subject'

```
library(data.table)
unique(old_data[Counter == 5, ], by = c('Subject'))
```

---

Or another option is `match` where `match` returns the index of the first row that matches and use that to subset

```
old_data[match(5, Counter)]
```